laravel error: Target class [validator] does not exist
I want to add a captcha to my login form. i use this package:
https://github.com/mewebstudio/captcha.
i do all step he say in document and in the last step ( php artisan vendor:publish ) i have this error.
 Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 

  Target class [validator] does not exist.

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:940
    936▕ 
    937▕         try {
    938▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    939▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  ➜ 940▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    941▕         }
    942▕ 
    943▕         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    944▕         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

  1   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}()
      +15 vendor frames 

  17  [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}()

after that i use these commands as a solution
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:clear
composer dump-autoload
composer install
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Mews\Captcha\CaptchaServiceProvider"
and get same error.
i use php:8.3 and laravel 11.9
sorry about my bad English.
try: php artisan vendor:publish
result: Target class [validator] does not exist.

Try to remove "vendor" directory and re-install it :)). I don't know, maybe it works.

Are you sure the problem is in any way related to Composer?
